# Change color of distribution plot in qlik sense

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I have a distribution plot in qlik sense:

[image]

How can I specify the color of the dots? I want to change it based on the points. 
I have three different types of my x-axis 'Geschäftsverteilung' : 'On-Time', 'Delayed' and 'Late', so the on-time are red right now and should be green, the delayed are blue and should be yellow and the late ones are yellow and should be red.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set to change colors by expression something like that:

```
If(Sum([# Purchases]) > 6,Green(),Red())
```

### [image]

To provide exact answer I would need to see your file and know what exactly you want to achieve (what colors for what results)

Comment: can't you just share qvw file with chart and data used by it. Will be much more simple for me